# Oversensitivity and Glitches in Automatic Posting Ban

Tags: discussion, feature-request, post-ban

I tried to post a question today but was given the "You have reached your question limit" message. Now, I understand this is to weed out accounts that are posting large numbers of poor questions. It told me I had last posted a question 1 day ago and needed to wait 1 day before posting.

At first I was confused as to why I would be under this ban so quickly. I've posted two questions. One was a month and a half ago and received a couple good answers. The second was a day ago and hasn't seen any answers or votes yet, and only a handful of views.

I realized that I had forgotten to accept one of the answers on the first question, so I went back and did that, thinking that might have affected things. But then when I went back and tried to post again, it now says it's been 0 days since posting a question and that I have to wait 2 days.

First of all (subjectively of course) I think this is *way* too sensitive. The questions received no downvotes, and one has only been up for a day. Second, it looks like, somehow, the ban is getting pushed into the future and is going on longer than it initially said it would despite posting no questions.

Just wondering what's going on here and what to do about it.

## The Cause

> It looks like the ban probably came from a deleted answer. I'm not sure why a deleted answer would cause a ban on questions instead of answers, but that's probably it. A ban for one deleted comment still seems way too sensitive. I have two other positively voted answers, one of which was a direct correction of the deleted one.
>
> Despite the initial 1 day increasing to 2 days with no explanation, it looks like the time does run down properly. I'm not sure what caused that but it's probably just an odd rounding error.

## Feature Request

> The `feature-request` tag refers to a couple possible elements.
>
> First, an answer deletion here caused a question posting ban. I'm not sure if this the intended result, but it would make sense that deleted answers would be more likely to cause an answer ban, and that deleted questions would be more likely to cause a question ban.
>
> Second, the threshold (based on my personal experience of a ban after a single answer) might be a little low. I think that one deletion shouldn't cause you to be banned from posting. Two or *maybe* three would be more reasonable.
>
> Third, in the case of a deletion, I would like to see a system where you can "fix" a deleted answer (or question) and if a moderator approves your fix, it can be reinstated without the deletion penalty. Obviously limits would have to be in place to avoid abuse.

Comment: Check for **deleted** questions in your questions view; there is a link at the bottom showing recent questions that have been deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That would have explained it, but I don't have any deleted questions.

Comment: You don't have any that were asked *recently* at least. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've only ever posted 2 questions, so no, I know for a fact that I don't have any. :)

Comment: We'll have to wait for a moderator then to see what is going on here.

Comment: I don't really know what I am talking about here, but I seem to remember that these limits take into account questions posted from the same ip, for accounts with less than 150 karma. Is it possible that someone else is sharing your ip address?

Comment: Nope. I think the cause was the incorrect link - it was deleted so fast I didn't realize it was wrong, then posted the right one, but that apparently was enough to instaban me.

Comment: A wrong link should not cause a post to be deleted, unless it is spam, so should not be able to cause any ban. As long as the rest of the post is at least an attempt to answer, albeit wrong, the worst that is supposed to happen are downvotes and harsh comments. A link without any accompanying answer may be another matter, those can get deleted without warning, whether right or wrong.

Comment: @HugoRune It was a valid link, but it was the wrong one and I didn't really describe it well (it was my first answer on the site here). Nobody asked for clarification either, it was just deleted with no explanation. Otherwise I would have been able to correct it. And when one deleted answer is all it takes to ban you, that's kind of a problem.

Comment: Link-only answers are automatically placed in a review queue for low-quality answers, and deleted if found wanting, so that may be what happened here. Nevertheless i would be surprised if that single answer is enough for a ban, especially since you were able to post another answer directly afterwards. There are however certain rate limits in place, that get increased with further positive contributions. You posted 3 answers and a question on the same day, one of them deleted, that may have hit your current limit.

Comment: @HugoRune That sounds like it could be why. StackOverflow sure is a hostile place for new users! :P

Comment: It's a temporary "ban", @Hugo - really, just a rate-limit. The idea is, rather than applying increasingly-strict rate-limits to *everyone*, we selectively apply them to folks who might benefit the most from taking a bit of extra time to learn about how we do things. As they continue to participate, most users "grow out of" the rate limits.

Comment: @Shog9 I have an idea. When an answer is deleted, allow the user to revise the answer and then submit it to be reconsidered. If the moderator sees that the revision is good, then the deletion is reversed and the answer is reset to zero votes as if it's a new answer. That would have prevented this whole problem. I'm not sure how much attention the developers pay to this forum or how best to suggest this as a possible improvement.

Comment: You can post a [meta-tag:feature-request] here if you want; auto-clearing votes is not going to be a popular suggestion though, as it would be very easy to abuse this. The vast majority of the time, posting a new answer (as you did) will be the preferred solution, as it accomplishes *almost* exactly the same thing without the need for moderator review. The truth is, you just got unlucky: the system was designed to catch the sort of new user who posts his "question" as an answer until he gets answer-banned, then starts posting questions until he gets question-banned.

Comment: @RainmanNoodles "*I have an idea. When an answer is deleted, allow the user to revise the answer and then submit it to be reconsidered*" When a user answers, they have all the time in the world to write a constructive/quality answer before pushing "Submit", and a *preview* of their answer showing how it'll look when published, to ensure it's quality. There is a help section giving advice on writing *acceptable* and quality answers. This all avoids the need for moderators having to check revisions of a user's bad answer, which is not really a good use of (precious) moderator time.

Comment: @James Still, mistakes can be made, such as pasting a right site/wrong article link. There would certainly be a limit on how many times you could revise, i.e. if you revised your answer and it was deleted again, you would have to submit a new one. I guess being burned like I was is pretty unlucky and unusual, and I doubt this would really gain any traction unless it affected a larger number of people.

Comment: @RainmanNoodles I totally agree, we all make mistakes, I often facepalm then edit my answer even after meticulously checking it. However I think it's fair to say that "usually" mistakes which would get the answer *deleted* are not "mistakes" and are in fact a poor answer. Yours possibly being a *very* rare occasion where the mistake made it a poor answer (although having not seen the answer, perhaps it depended on the link too much even if it had been the correct link?)

Comment: @James One problem was that I didn't really explain the link and just said "Here's your answer." The article in the link was supposed to be an exact answer for the question, word for word. Unfortunately the link I posted was actually a second article on the same site that explained a slightly different aspect of the same topic; it answered some parts but wasn't complete. I think the people who deleted it probably just looked at it and assumed it was spam without bothering to read it, which, given that I had somewhere around 5 (?) rep at the time, is understandable.

Comment: @RainmanNoodles "*One problem was that I didn't really explain the link and just said Here's your answer.*" That might have been the *main* problem. Link only answers, even if to the correct article/page/site, are frowned upon. If the article/site goes down, or is taken down, website retires, etc, then the answer here on Stack is also gone. so, link only answers are not really future proof, and so are classed as a poor answer (or, not an answer in your case as incorrect link).

Comment: Sounds like the system worked as intended.  New user posts low-quality answer that gets properly deleted, gets a 2 day ban (reasonable I think), and learns something about how to write good questions and answers in the process.

Comment: Rainman Noodles/noodles/noodlesstillalive - perhaps an anti-pastaite conspiracy?

Comment: @Magoo I... uh... don't get it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Now that you _are_ a mod, your first comment looks a bit silly.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: meta contains plenty of comments by moderators from before their election, and of users that were once moderators. I'm certainly not going to find all of those that are mine!

Comment: @MartijnPieters And for each of them, it looks a bit silly. There's nothing wrong with it; I just thought it would be funny to point out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answers count too - both for and against.

Comment: I didn't know that. I've posted two answers, one with +2 and one with +1 votes. The +1 was a replacement for an answer where I had mistakenly posted the wrong link (it was the same site but a different page) and it was deleted within a couple minutes before I could correct it. Could that be what's causing it?

Comment: And in that case, if you post the wrong link in an answer, how do you correct it if it's already been deleted? Was posting a new answer with the correct link the wrong approach?

Comment: Are the FAQ entries for question and answer bans incorrect/out of date in that case? Or are they something slightly different? They show a different message to the one given in this question, and seem to suggest that banning from questions and answers happens independently:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans
http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans

Comment: Deleting your answer wasn't a problem, Rainman. Leaving it up long enough to attract 4 downvotes and 3 delete votes hurt a bit. That said, this isn't particularly severe right now - you've already attracted upvotes on your other answers, and your questions have been well-received thus far, so I wouldn't be too concerned - look at it as a learning opportunity.

Comment: They've never been fully independent, @Jo, particularly for new users. That said, the article you're looking for is http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited

Comment: @Shog9 - thanks! Looks like that doesn't mention answers mattering, either - on the one hand I can understand not wanting to fully reveal the algorithm, but it does seem a bit too unclear to be really helpful. The FAQ focuses very heavily on improving your *questions*, including links to how to do this and what to avoid, but doesn't discuss how to improve your answers.

Comment: There's really no reason to even think about answers most of the time, @Jo - first, because it's unlikely you can do *anything* about it, and second because any time you're willing to spend is probably best spent on improving your questions - an upvoted question counts for a lot. The only reason these checks look at answers is because for very new users they tend to provide a useful bit of signal in cases where someone's struggling to understand the local culture and needs a "heads-up" before they end up digging themselves into a hole.

Comment: @Shog9 It got the votes within about 3 minutes. When I noticed the link was the wrong one I tried to edit it, but by the time I had changed it it was already deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a consideration factor for why SO includes answers in this criteria or not, but I often see new users posting questions as answers. This could be a good reason for answer votes to count towards the question posting ban.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280915/oversensitivity-and-glitches-in-automatic-posting-ban/280917?noredirect=1#comment132861_280915 @Tom ;-)